# Register in IEEE A ranked conferences - Student or full registration?

Tags: peer-review, conference, ieee

I am trying to follow up with the instructions to register my paper for the conference. However, the system is not allowing me to finish the process.

I just emailed the editor and he answered after a while, seems quite busy to explain. So I am assuming that if I asked him again for an explanation would take a lot of time too.

'' That error message is telling you to need to pay the full registration. In the instructions at "Fees and Registrations" appears that each student needs a full registration for its paper in order to be able to pay the student's fee. For example, if you wrote your paper with a professor, your professor should pay the full registration so you can pay student's.'' can any help what that means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That seems clearly written to me. You aren't allowed to present a paper unless at least one of its authors has paid full registration. Maybe ethically questionable, but clear. What is your doubt? Have you read the instructions to which you were referred? Do they confirm it?

EDIT after your comment: "full registration" very likely means "IEEE member" or "non-IEEE member" (whichever applies).

Comment: I am a PhD student where the final author is my supervisor. Actually, in the registration form, there is nothing called full registration. it either IEEE Member 
Non - IEEE Member 
Student IEEE Member 
Student Non - IEEE Member 
Life/Retired IEEE Member 
Participant without paper